# ATAES132a Status Register showing 0x40

Tags: cryptography, aes, microchip

Whenever I connect the chip to the pc and I read status register (0xFFF0), it gives me the value 0x40.

This happens when there is a response block ready to be read.

Even when I read the response block and check the status register again, it gives me the value 0x40.

If I disconnect the chip and short the terminal and then connect again, it gives me the value 0x00 which is expected value. Can anybody help me understand what's happening ?

Answer (score 0):

You had to reset the flag with the `RESET` command at address 0x00. Have a look at the datasheet.

Comment: But  Why I have to reset? 

I execute a command and read resonse. After that check the status register. The bit that is high is telling me that response block is ready to be read even after I read it.